# Displaying multiple columns of categories on a specific a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to list all terms on a custom taxonomy but I wanted to at least group them into 3 columns including their children to have a visual balance. Here's what I've done so far. I'm stuck on creating the loop after it reached the maximum term. On what I have, It wrapped all the succeeding items with 'ul' instead of creating a second ul and list the next batch.  After it reaches the x amount of term it should create another 'ul' element listing categories in it. There will be a total of 3 columns.

```
    <?php 

        $get_cats = wp_list_categories( 'echo=0&title_li=&depth=2&hide_empty=0,&taxonomy=industries' );
        // Split into array items

        $cat_array = explode('</li>',$get_cats);
        // Amount of categories (count of items in array)
        $results_total = count($cat_array);
        // How many categories to show per list (round up total divided by 3)
        $cats_per_list = ceil($results_total / 3);
        // Counter number for tagging onto each list
        $list_number = 1;
        // Set the category result counter to zero
        $result_number = 0;
        ?>

        <?php echo $cats_per_list ; ?>

        <ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-<?php echo $list_number; ?>">

        <?php
        foreach($cat_array as $category) {

            $result_number++;

            if($result_number >= $cats_per_list) {
                $list_number++;
                echo $category.'</li> </ul> <ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-'.$list_number.'">';
            }
            else {
                echo $category.'</li>';
            }

        }
        ?>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is very buggy. Just a couple of observations:

Next in the

```
if($result_number >= $cats_per_list) {
```

Block you are going to have to reset result_number to 0 since the count starts over again.  Your current code would only meet that condition once since $cats_per_list is defined as the average of the total amount. After that it would continue counting up and ALWAYS be >= $cats_per_list

Next: it's quibble but you probably don't need to ceil the result since you are using >=, that operation pretty much does the same thing since 1.5 will meet the criteria of >= 1 as a for instance.

Try this and see if it is any better:

```
   <?php 

        $get_cats = wp_list_categories( 'echo=0&title_li=&depth=2&hide_empty=0,&taxonomy=industries' );
        // Split into array items

        $cat_array = explode('</li>',$get_cats);
        // Amount of categories (count of items in array)
        $results_total = count($cat_array);
        // How many categories to show per list (round up total divided by 3)
        $cats_per_list = ceil($results_total / 3);
        // Counter number for tagging onto each list
        $list_number = 1;
        // Set the category result counter to zero
        $result_number = 0;
        ?>

        <?php echo $cats_per_list ; ?>

        <ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-<?php echo $list_number; ?>">

        <?php
        foreach($cat_array as $category) {

            $result_number++;

            if($result_number >= $cats_per_list) {
$result_number = 0;
                $list_number++;
                echo $category.'</li> </ul> <ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-'.$list_number.'">';
            }
            else {
                echo $category.'</li>';
            }

        }
        ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I appreciate for checking out my code. Although, I wasn't still able to figure out how to display the list items on column. When I tried your suggestion, the succeeding columns where nested on the first column, which should not be the case. I'm trying to distribute all the <li>'s on the 3 columns. I've also tried to modify this line 

echo $category.'</li> </ul> <ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-'.$list_number.'">';

thinking it would fix the problem.

Comment: here's the output I got when I tried to your suggestion. Notice that the columns are nested on the main column and the 2nd column listed only few items where there should be at least 68 items to be listed. on the last column it really didn't list any items at all.

http://pastebin.com/GxxJUJ5k